# How to expose child control style properties in a custom composite WebControl

Tags: asp.net, coding-style, designer, web-controls

I am writing a custom composite WebControl and want to expose styles of child controls it encapsulates to the ASP.NET designer.  The code I currently have is similar to the skeleton below (which for simplicity only has one child control).

With the code below, I can see property "ChildPanelStyle" in the designer, but when I try to modify one of the properties (e.g. CssClass) in the designer, it immediately resets itself to its default value.  It looks like the designer serialization isn't happening.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Adding a setter for the style property doesn't help and shouldn't be necessary. I've updated the sample with an additional style property that is managed directly by the custom control, rather than simply being the property of a child control.

The HeaderStyle property is persisted properly by the designer, but the ChildPanelStyle property isn't.

Of course I could manage all my styles like HeaderStyle, and apply them during rendering, but I'm hoping there's a simpler solution whereby child controls can take care of themselves, and I don't need any custom rendering.

```
public class MyControl : CompositeControl
{
    Panel myChildPanel;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        myChildPanel = new Panel();
        this.Controls.Add(myChildPanel);
    }

    [
    Category("Style"),
    Description("Child panel style"),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    NotifyParentProperty(true),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
    ]
    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style ChildPanelStyle
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            return this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle;
        }
    }

    [
    Category("Style"),
    Description("Header style"),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    NotifyParentProperty(true),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
    ]
    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style HeaderStyle
    {
        get
        {
            if (_headerStyle == null)
            {
                _headerStyle = new Style();
                if (IsTrackingViewState)
                    ((IStateManager)_headerStyle).TrackViewState();
            }
            return _headerStyle;
        }
    }
    private System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style _headerStyle;

    // ... overrides for save/load/tracking ViewState omitted 

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        base.Render(writer);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you got this solved? I'm creating a composite control with the same style property for the inner child control. Hopefully you can share your code.

Answer (score 1):

You've got no setter.  Unfortunately, you can't directly set this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle, as it's a read-only property, so you'll have to set *it's* properties.  Change your ChildPanelStyle property to the following:

```
[
Category("Style"),
Description("Child panel style"),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
NotifyParentProperty(true),
PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
]
public System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style ChildPanelStyle
{
    get
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        return this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle;
    }
    set
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.BackColor = value.BackColor;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.BorderColor = value.BorderColor;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.BorderStyle = value.BorderStyle;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.BorderWidth = value.BorderWidth;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.CssClass = value.CssClass;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.Font.Bold = value.Font.Bold;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.Font.Italic = value.Font.Italic;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.Font.Name = value.Font.Name;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.Font.Names = value.Font.Names;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.Font.Overline = value.Font.Overline;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.Font.Size = value.Font.Size;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.Font.Strikeout = value.Font.Strikeout;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.Font.Underline = value.Font.Underline;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.ForeColor = value.ForeColor;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.Height = value.Height;
        this.myChildPanel.ControlStyle.Width = value.Width;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding a setter and it made no difference - which is what I expected.  I updated my sample to show a case where a style managed directly by the property works fine in the designer, without a setter.

Comment: BTW wouldn't it be possible for the setter to update the ControlStyl using something like             myChildPanel.ControlStyle.Reset();
            myChildPanel.ControlStyle.MergeWith(value);

Answer (score 0):

If your control derived from System.Web.UI.Control (which most likely is true according to simptoms), you should add the following attributes to get what you want:

```
[ParseChildren(true)]
[PersistChildren(false)]
public class MyControl : CompositeControl
{
    ...
}
```

This is not nesessary when deriving from WebControl.

---

PS
you do not need setter for ...Style properties - but ensure those styles are really created upon first attempt to get them.